# What is $\int \frac{-2}{x^2-1}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, logarithms, hyperbolic-functions

For $x\in\mathbb{R}$, what is the value of
$$
\int \frac{-2}{x^2-1}\,dx?
$$
Using partial fractions, we get
$$
 \int \frac{-2}{x^2-1}\,dx= \int \frac{1}{x+1}\,dx+ \int \frac{-1}{x-1}\,dx=\log|x+1|-\log|1-x|+C=\log \left|\frac{x+1}{1-x} \right|+C
$$
for all $x\in\mathbb{R}\backslash \{-1,1\}$. However, using the substitution $x = \tanh u$, we get
$$
 \int \frac{-2}{x^2-1}\,dx= -2\int\frac{\text{sech}^2 u}{\tanh^2u-1} \,du=2u+C=2\tanh^{-1} x+C
$$
which only hold for $|x|<1$. For this interval, the identity $2\tanh^{-1} x=\log\left( \frac{1+x}{1-x} \right)$ [holds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_functions). However, I believe that only the first answer is correct, for all $x\in\mathbb{R}\backslash \{-1,1\}$. What am I missing here? Is it because this substitution only holds for $|x|<1$ and therefore I am restricting the evaluation of the integral to this domain? Or are these answers equivalent up to a constant?

Comment: As a side note, by restricting, $x\in\Bbb R$, one restricts the solutions $2\text{Re}(\tanh^{-1}(x)), 2\text{Re}(\coth^{-1}(x))$ which [work](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=2+Re%5Barctanh%28x%29%5D%2C+2+Re%5Barccoth%28x%29%5D) for all $x\in\Bbb R$

Comment: If you substitute $x=\tanh u$, then you are saying $|x|<1$

Comment: Tyma that is great! I forgot to check the other identity! A branching function could replace the logarithm version then. I guess the $\coth^{-1}$ is obtainable under a different substitution?

Comment: @samwolfe You would get $2\coth^{-1}(x),|x|>1$ and $2\tanh^{-1}(x),|x|<1$ where both have $x\in\Bbb R$. Likely when substituting $x=\coth(u)$ you are saying $|x|>1$.

Comment: Exactly! This answers it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since $\exp (x \pm \pi i/2) =  \pm ie^x$, we have
\begin{align*}
\tanh \left(x + \frac{\pi i}{2}\right) = \frac{ie^{x} + i e^{-x}}{i e^{-x} - i e^{-x}} = \frac{1}{\tanh x};
\end{align*}
that is,
\begin{align*}
\tanh^{-1} \frac{1}{x} = \frac{\pi i}{2} + \tanh^{-1} x.
\end{align*}
(I'm glossing over the matter of defining the range of $\tanh^{-1}$ properly, since $\tanh$ has period $\pi i$.) We also have
\begin{align*}
\left|\frac{1 + x^{-1}}{1 - x^{-1}}\right| = \left|\frac{x+1}{x - 1}\right| = \left|\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right|
\end{align*}
for $x\not = 0, 1$. The upshot is that we can reconcile the two integrands by taking $x \to 1/x$ and, up to a constant of integration, extend the result for $|x| < 1$ to all real $x\not = -1, 1$. This constant of integration is going to be complex, but that's because the substitution $x \to \tanh^{-1} x$ is only real-valued for $|x| < 1$.